# text overlap on image issues in firefox

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image: overlap]

Image is showing perfect in desktop & mobile media query, but when i see my page in tablet it shows some issues regarding overlap type. 
I already uploaded the snap. 
please tell me how to fix this issue. my source code is shown below. 
I tried my best but i don't know how to debug it. 
Please solve it as soons as possible. I have already update the viewport width from 80 to 100 but still problem remains same.

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="mividamylife.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light+Two">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Brand -->
    <div class="brand"> 
       <a href="index.html">
        <h3 class="name">LOURDES GABRIELA</h3>
        <h5 class="incorporated">I n t e r i o r s,  I n c.</h5>
       </a>
    </div> 

    <!-- Nav Links for Phone-->
    <div class="nav-phone" style="hidden">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Projects.html">Projects</a>
        <a href="MiVidaMyLife.html">MiVidaMyLife</a>
        <a href="Media.html">Media</a>
        <a href="Artwork.html">Artwork</a>
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>  
    </div>

    <!-- Box -->
    <div class="newbox">
        <div class="readiblecolumns">

            <div class="profile">
                <img src="Pictures/MiVidaMyLife/mividapicture.jpg" alt="">
            </div>

            <div>
               <p>I was born in Cuba and raised in Panama. Though I left Panama at 17 to attend Vassar College. Panama in many ways will always be embedded in my psyche: memories of the down pouring tropical storms while sitting on our veranda or deep sea fishing in the turquoise waters of the Caribbean; the impromptu cocktail parties or the formal dinners fit for a king; and last but by no means least, the open doors that welcomed friends at any time, day or night. These early experiences have had an immense influence on my sense of lifestyle.<br><br>I went abroad to New York to study at Vassar College, a bastion of liberal arts in the 70’s. My B.A. was in Literature, but my interests were limitless. I studied Art History with the distinguished Art Historian, Professor Linda Nochlin, sculpture with the prolific sculptor Sydney Geist. My painting professor taught us to experience art beyond something hung on the wall or put on a pedestal in a museum. At Vassar I learned how to think and examine the root of a question as a way of answering it critically and most importantly I was taught to see.<br><br>I went abroad to Paris and continued my studies in French Literature, Art History and Classical Architecture. As a young woman living in Paris, I took every possible opportunity to travel and experience the art and architecture of Europe. Paris in the late 70’s released the free spirit in me, freeing me from inhibitions and unleashing a sense of fearlessness that has had a formative influence on me as a designer.<br><br>498 7th Avenue in Manhattan is where I began my career in the world of fashion, becoming the Fashion Director for Sasson Jeans and then Jordache until the late 80’s when I moved to Miami. I set the fashion trends and traveled regularly to Paris, London, Milan, Rome, St Tropez, Florence, Hong Kong and Japan.The key to great design in fashion is to create what will be wanted. The key to great design in interiors is capturing the spirit of the client and the essence of the space.<br><br>I now live in Miami and summer in the mountains of western North Carolina. It was my fashion background, as well as the knowledge I gained from the study of art, that led me to interior decorating. I continue to paint and travel the world looking for the next cool, one-of-a-kind object, pattern or detail that will be the inspiration for my next project.</p>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Nav Links -->
    <div class="nav">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Projects.html">Projects</a>
        <a href="MiVidaMyLife.html">MiVidaMyLife</a>
        <a href="Media.html">Media</a>
        <a href="Artwork.html">Artwork</a>
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>  
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="signature">
            <p>a boutique design company - miami</p>
        </div>
    </footer>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

main.css


#profile_text
{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.nav-phone>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.nav>a:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #fbc076;
}

.newbox {
    background-color: white;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.readiblecolumns {
    background-color: white;
}

.readiblecolumns>p {
    line-height: 1;
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width:80vw;
    }

    /* Reads Like Newspaper */
    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 90%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 480px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        //margin-right:20px;
        padding-right:20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 959px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 80vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 80vw;
        padding: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        height: 320px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .profile img {
        height: 100%;
        background-attachment:fixed;
        width: 100px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

}

/* Phone */
@media screen and (max-width: 519px) {

    .newbox {
        height: auto;
        width: 90vw;
    }

    .readiblecolumns {
        width: 90vw;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .readiblecolumns>p {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    .profile {
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .profile img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 5%;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to simplify the problem down to minimal components and try to debug the issue yourself. Dumping the entire source and saying hurry and fix my problem is not a way to get your question answered on SO (or anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: Can you make this work in a jsfiddle please

Comment: the website of mine is http://www.lourdesgabrielainteriors.com/MiVidaMyLife.html

Comment: Please open it in firefox, and set it in tablet size.

Comment: Problem occurs only in tablet media query

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any code related to Bootstrap on any page in your website yet you have two different versions of Bootstrap JS loading on pages and jQuery loaded twice on some as well. You should also check which version of Firefox your error is happening on because it does not appear in the latest builds.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using bootstrap. You need to restructure your html and use bootstrap's grid layout which is made to be responsive, you will not have this problem then. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid